# set a text from a java object with new lines to a javascript variable in JSP

Tags: javascript, jsp

I've a Java String with new lines(\n), say for example

```
String value = "This is a variable\n\nfrom\nJava";
```

Now I've to set this to a Javascript variable in a JSP file,

```
<script>var val = '<%= value %>';</script>
```

But because of the new lines in the above line, I'm getting javascript error "Unterminated String".

Please help me.

Comment: This is an XSS hole; (correctly) answering the question will close the hole.

Comment: @SLaks: valid point if it's a fully client-controlled value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Newlines will be only one issue. To properly escape the string for display as a JavaScript literal, you have to handle newlines and a wide variety of other characters (not least backslashes and whatever quotes you're using). This isn't hard, but it's non-trivial. Effectively you need to search the string for a range of values (regular expressions are useful here) and substitute the JavaScript escape code (`\n`, etc.) for it. To avoid charset issues, when doing this sort of thing I escape anything that isn't ASCII into either the JavaScript named escape (`\n`) or a Unicode escape (`\u1234`).

Answer (score 6):

Use [`StringEscapeUtils#escapeEcmaScript()`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeEcmaScript%28java.lang.String%29) before printing it to JSP.

Comment: Big +1, don't reinvent the wheel.